# AWS Lambda function: returns null on querying postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS. I am trying to connect to AWS RDS postgreSQL instance and query it using Lambda function. It returns null. Below is my code.

```
  var { Pool } = require('pg');
  exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  var dbConfig = {
    username: '<username>',
    password: '<password>',
    database: '<database>',
    host: '<db-endpoint>',
  };
  var pool = new Pool(dbConfig);
  exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    pool.connect();
    pool.query("select NOW() as now", (err, res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      if (err) return callback(err);
        if (res.rows.length==0){

            return callback(null, null);
        }
        else{
            return callback(null, res.rows[0]);
        }  
    });
 };
```

Comment: Put some debug logging in there to make sure it (a) follows the code path you're expecting, and (b) is in fact null (i.e. print out res before calling the callback). Alternatively try removing `async` from the handler.

Answer (score 2):

Giri,

Your AWS Lambda needs proper permission to access AWS RDS (PostgreSQL). You have to create an Execution Role and get attached to the Lambda Service.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html

Attached are a couple of images to show the results.
[image]

[image]

Once you have successfully done this, You can jump into setting-up the Lambda package with code and driver to connect to AWS RDS PostGreSQL. Below 2 links will guide you through that.
https://medium.com/@ly.lee/connecting-aws-lambda-node-js-to-redshift-or-postgresql-try-aws-lambda-layers-78e60c27f39b

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html